# There is an error popped up when typing "import FBSDKLoginKit"

Tags: ios, swift, facebook, fbsdkloginkit

I have strictly followed the percedures shown on website, wanting to use facebook account to login on my designed app. But when I type `import FBSDKLoginKit` below the sentence `"import FBSDKCoreKit"`, system gives me an error saying that: `Could not build an Objective-C module 'FBSDKLoginKit'`.  I do not know why there is no `error` on the tutorial video but it is for me. `(I'm using swift to implement my app)`
   Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: Are you using the bridging header?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you added the appropriate frameworks just copy and paste this into your file header

import FBSDKLoginKit

If not check your build phases and double check

This video may also be helpful
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cpANieebE2M

Not to mention it is always better to follow the frameworks docs first. Facebook gives detailed step by step documentation to use their api.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/getting-started

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/ios